# How to set up proxy in your script and publish a topic using mqtt-paho in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, paho

The below code will run perfectly in my home network but when i am using my office network it wont, throwing some error. So i thought to use proxy in my script, again after that getting some proxy related error .

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import time
import socket
import socks


broker = 'iot.eclipse.org'

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print('Connected OK')
    else:
        print('Bad Connection returned code=', rc)
        # print("CONNACK received with code %d." % (rc))


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print('log :' + buf)


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print('Disconnected result code ', str(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print('topic: '+msg.topic, 'payload: '+str(msg.payload))


client = paho.Client('python2')
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_log = on_log
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, 'proxyhost.com', 1180)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
print('Connecting to broker', broker)
client.connect(broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe('test/iotglab')
client.publish('test/iotglab', 'Hello Client')
time.sleep(4)
client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

I got proxy which is look like socks5h://hostname.com.